# SAAS Multitenant DB Design

Tags: sql-server, database, saas, multi-tenant, database-performance

I started developing an SaaS based application and involving in Data Base design with SQL Server 2008.

I am using Shared DB instance for the application. I mean only one Data base that have all the client/tenant records identified by TenantId/ClientId.

After some discussion, i decided to change all the identifier of my all tables to GUID rather than auto incremental id.

The primary reason for doing this

1. Moving/merging one client data to another new host will be easy with help of GUID

But i feel making GUID as identifier will be slow when we do JOIN. 
The database will have over all 100 Clients and each client will have 10,000 Records.

Could some one suggest me some idea for implementing this approach with good performance?

Comment: for multitenant GUID based PK approach has been discussed [ here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911447/sql-server-is-a-guid-based-pk-the-best-practice-to-support-tenant-based-horizon) to know more about GUID vs int [go here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504905/is-it-better-to-use-an-uniqueidentifierguid-or-a-bigint-for-an-identity-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i feel making GUID as identifier will be very slow when we do JOIN

I would suggest trying to get over your irrational "feelings" unless they are backed up with evidence.  That will probably solve your problem

Comment: So making GUID will not impact performance when we do join with a table of 1000000 records?

Comment: Was going through this so asked . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/guid-as-primary-key-best-practices

Comment: There will be a small impact, but nowhere near a change from "fast" to "very slow". http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=25862